# How does MariaDB handle simultaneous inserts of duplicate primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, deadlock

Test case hypothetical

My whatever Java or C++ application runs on a cluster of let’s say 100 virtual computes. Every Instance of this application makes a simultaneous INSERT into MariaDB on Galera (100 simultaneous inserts )

```
insert into test_table (id_col) values (1)
```

What will happen? Obviously there is a duplicate primary key violation. But will at least one of these INSERT statements succeed? Is it guaranteed? Is deadlock possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the 100 connections are all on a single Galera node:

One will succeed; the rest will fail on the `INSERT`.

If the 100 connections are spit across your 3(?) Galera nodes:

On the node where the successful insert occurs, others will fail on `INSERT`.

On the other nodes, failure will occur on `COMMIT`.

If you are running with `autocommit=ON`, then there is an *implicit* `COMMIT` in the `INSERT`, so the failures will seem to be the same.  However, there may be some detail status that is different.

Remote actions (insert on this node, but some other node already has the row committed) are optimistic, so must be caught on the `COMMIT`.

In reality, it is very hard to get 100 connections to do an `INSERT` "simultaneously".  I doubt if you could get even 10 to happen.  At several stages of the operation, Mutexes are taken out, thereby briefly single-threading work on a node.  And the overhead of launching a connection is probably larger than that trivial `INSERT`.

Also, keep in mind that all the connections are probably going through a single Ethernet network.  This also tends to prevent as much simultaneity as you were expecting.

Is it guaranteed that one of the `INSERTs` will succeed?  I think so.  Otherwise, what good is the database engine?  Production systems have been pounding on InnoDB for about 16 years.  Galera has been in production for maybe 6 years.  A lost `INSERT` would be a critical bug, no matter how it occurred.